# How to condense a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following jquery/javascript function that gets values from json data and adds them to a variable:

```js
function get_class_classes(data) {
   var terms = data.terms, // setup shortcut data path
   classList = '';         // setup blank var to add string values to

   for (child = 0; child < terms.day.length; child++) {
       classList += terms.day[child].slug + ' ';
   }
   for (child = 0; child < terms.medium.length; child++) {
       classList += terms.medium[child].slug + ' ';
   }
   for (child = 0; child < terms.term.length; child++) {
       classList += terms.term[child].slug + ' ';
   }
   for (child = 0; child < terms.type.length; child++) {
       classList += terms.type[child].slug + ' ';
   }

   return classList;
}
```

## Question:

Is there a cleaner way for me to set this up, meaning, condense all of those `for` loops into something more succinct?

Here is what I have tried:

```
function get_class_classes(data) {
    var terms = data.terms, // setup shortcut
    termsArray = ['day', 'medium', 'term', 'type'],
    classList = '';         // setup blank var

    for ( i=0; i < termsArray.length; i++ ) {
        var currentTerm = termsArray[i];

        for (child = 0; child < terms.currentTerm.length; child++) { // loop through each day, add term slug to daylis
            classList += terms.currentTerm[child].slug + ' ';
        }
     }

  return classList;
}
```

This returns the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I also moved the `var terms = data.terms` to the loop, which allowed the function to work, but `classList` returned filled with 'undefined' rather than the real value.

## Sample of `data`

`data` is a json object, loosely formatted something the following, which I copied from the console:

```
terms: Object
    day: Array[2]
        0: Object
            ID: 197
            name: "Thursday"
            slug: "thursday"
        1: Object
     medium: Array[1]
        0: Object
            ID: 200
            name: "Painting"
            slug: "painting"
        /* Continues for variable amount of objects. Same is true for `term` and and `type` */
```

**If you happen to answer and know why my method did not work**, an explanation would be great to have for future reference/thought processes.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a sample of what `data.terms` looks like?

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but you are defining `i` and `child` as global variables, which is usually not what you really want to do. use `var i = 0;` and `var child = 0;` as the first statements in your `for` loops to declare them in the local scope.

Comment: Have you looked at underscore library? It cleans up repetitive code pretty well when used right

Comment: try terms[currentTerm].length; instead of terms.currentTerm.length

Comment: are `terms.day`,`terms.medium`, etc. all the same length? ie, is there a reason to loop through each array individually?

Comment: Updated with a sample of data @ChrisBaker.

Comment: @patrickgunderson - all have variable length, and the slug of each needs to be added to the elements class once the element is generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the access of `terms.currentTerm.length` to be `terms[currentTerm].length`. That should fix your error.

**Explanation**

In the first iteration of the first `for` loop, for example, `terms.currentTerm` does not access `terms.day`. It instead accesses the property named `currentTerm` on your `terms` object. This property does not exist—`terms` has no property named `currentTerm`—and trying to access `length` on an object that does not exist produces an error.

If you want to access a property on `terms` with the same name as the value of your `currentTerm` variable, use bracket notation so the value of `currentTerm` gets used instead: `terms[currentTerm]`. The interpreter "reads" this as `terms['day']`, which is what you really want.

Comment: This is the correct answer. As for the explanation: You can access attributes of javascript objects in two ways, either with `object['key']` or with `object.key`. When you use `terms.currentTerm` is assumes 'currentTerm' is the key, which is undefined. By using `terms[currentTerm]` instead, it uses the variable currentTerm wich resolves to the correct key string and returns the array you are expecting.

Comment: No, it doesn't say `terms.'day'`. Really not. It just says `terms.currentTerm` which is equivalent to `terms['currentTerm']`.

Comment: @Bergi I thought I was the only one to notice this answer *explanation* makes no sense.

Comment: What is the value of currentTerm? It is 'day'. So you are in essence using 'day' as the access key by saying terms.currentTerm which is not a valid way to access the property. If you want to use 'day' as the access key you need to access it using the bracket notation. How does this not make sense?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in my first comment it is not `terms.'day'` but instead `terms.currentTerm` with 'currentTerm' being the key that returns an undefined value. At the time I wrote this first comment there was no explanation on the answer at all, which is why I did not refer to the wrong explanation above.

Comment: @ChrisFranklin no, it does not resolve the variable when using `terms.currentTerm` but is just taking `currentTerm` as a key. You are right though, if you want to use 'day' as the key you either have to use `terms.day` or, especially when it is in a variable `terms['day']` (or accordingly `terms[currentTerm]`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! It looks like an edit was made that makes it a little clearer than the garbled explanation I put up there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but I can't really test it because I have no idea what data.terms is besides an array?

```
function get_class_classes(data){
        var terms = data.terms,
        termsArray = ['day', 'medium', 'term', 'type']
        classList = '';

        for(var term of terms){
            for(var termType of termsArray){
                for(var child of terms[termType]){
                    classList += child.slug + ' ';
                }
            }
        }

        return classList;
    }
```